# MLV (Modern Literal Version) translation: How reasonable is their "open source" claim?

Tags: bible-translation

The Modern Literal Version of the Bible (MLV) is described at their [website](http://www.modernliteralversion.org/). It claims to be based on the ASV, modified to agree with the Byzantine Greek text. They claim it has been proofread and corrected by a large number of people, also that there is a translation committee including scholars, and they describe it as being "open source". It is copyrighted but they are free with permissions to reproduce. There is not a true "open" license.

I am wondering if there is a way to verify their process. I don't see a repository with an edit history. Are they indeed "open" in their edit process, and can someone readily find past versions, preferably with an edit history?

From their site:

> The Modern Literal Version was created for those who truly want to
>   know what God's Koine Greek Bible says but cannot read it directly.
>   The largest Bible project in English history, over a million possible
>   proofreaders. The MLV is not owned by a publishing company, a
>   government, foundation, bible society or a church. Open Source as in
>   you (yes, you) can submit any correction that is not "Thus saith the
>   Greek."  We want to be "Error-free."

[Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modern_Literal_Version)